# Symfony 3.4 does not refresh my updates

Tags: apache, caching, symfony-3.4

I just start learning Symfony, I started with the version 3.4.
The first issue I faced is that whatever I changed in the view .twig files, Symfony renders the previous one at all.

I tried create a new twig. It displayed correctly, after that a changed its content but it does not respect any of my modification.

I turned off cache in the httpd.conf and in the browser. I try to restart apache and try to check in other browsers. So the result is the same, so the culprit is must be the Symfony. The final miracle: I cannot find where are the cached files...

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First  of  all - you need to  work on dev  envionment

if you have symfony on  domain.local (or  127.0.0.1:8080 for example) you need to enter  **domain.local/app_dev.php**  (or  127.0.0.1:8080/app_dev.php )  not  "/"

You can  clear  cache  from command  line

```
php bin/console  c:c  
php app/console  c:c       - for older sf  versions
```

Also you can simply delete all files in cache folder

**app/cache** - for older sf version

**var/cache** - for  3+ version